Minimum number of samples to effectively measure an effect
An interesting question came across my desk. With some hypothesized success rate, $p$, what is the minimum number of binomial trials needed to effectively measure this effect?
Given an infinite number of trials, we will certainly converge on the true success rater. But close enough is certainly some finite number. My question is, when do we experience diminishing returns where the value of one extra trial has a negligible effect on the estimated variance?
I asked the following question but I now believe that this Q/A is tangentially related.
Probability that >= m successes occur in n Binomial trials
I know that a one sample NHST can be performed but this would require $H_0=0$ that we aim to test/reject. However, the problem is not content to reject 0 but rather bound $p$ as closely as possible.

Once you suitably define "effectively measure", this is answerable. It will matter if you care about absolute error, relative error, or some other measure of accuracy. Because it's relying on random samples, it will involve a probability.  For absolute error in probability see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval where the biggest samples are needed for proportions in the ballpark of 50% ... however, with relative error the biggest samples are needed for the smallest proportions. Many posts on site address this.

Here is an example in R. You don't need to be able to read the code, I have just left it here if anyone is curious.
This is basically a "confidence analysis" way of looking at it. In this example, for a series of sample sizes of Bernoulli trials (1 to 200), I have calculated the 95% confidence interval on $p$ (arbitrarily 0.87 in this example) using the "exact" (or Clopper-Pearson) method.
You can see that there is certainly diminishing returns on the confidence as we add trials. However, what a "negligible effect" is, really depends on what you're actually trying to do. Maybe if you're doing a very expensive study, $n=25$ is acceptable. Maybe you are doing something with massive risk if $p$ is wrong, so you need to have huge $n$, say 1000 or so. There's no right answer.
library(binom)
library(ggplot2)
p <- 0.87
df <- binom.confint(
  x = round(1:200*p)
  , n = 1:200
  , conf.level = 0.95
  , methods = "exact"
)
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = n, y = mean)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = n, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)
              , alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(x = "Sample size", y = "Mean + CI")


